# Vertical+Horizontal Throw

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, coordinate-systems, projectile

From the top of a cliff, a stone is thrown vertically upwards with a speed of 21.8 m / s. From the same height, a second stone is dropped 3 s later. Both stones hit the ground simultaneously. Under these conditions, considering that there is no friction with the air and that the movement is carried out in a single dimension:
a)Determine the height of the cliff from which the stones are thrown.
b)Determine how long it takes for the first stone to reach maximum height and how long the latter is worth.

For b) I use that when the stone teach max height $v=0$ then $t=-v(0)/g  \Longrightarrow t=2.2s$. If we compute the height we obtain $-24.2m$(as we choose 0m on the cliff).

The i have problems to solve the a) I don't know how to solve using movement equations